# PSTricks Failing to Draw

Tags: xetex, pdf, pstricks

I'm trying to draw a simple graph with PSTricks for a mathematical paper, though I cannot for the life of me manage to do so. The package seems to have been correctly imported as I can run a PSTricks test document I found [online](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/psttest.tex). When I attempt to run the document in Texmaker, only a blank box appears. I've used numerous examples to no avail.

```
\begin{flalign*}
    \text{(a) } -4 &&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align*}
    &\left|z\right| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{(-4)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{16} = 4& \\
    &\tan \theta = \frac{0}{-4} = 0 & \\
    &\arctan (0) = 0, \pi& \\
    &z = 4(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)&
\end{align*}
\begin{pspicture}
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<-}(2,1)
\end{pspicture}
```

Results in:

[image]

Note that the large white space was filled with more equations prior to adding the PSTricks snippet.

I am compiling with XeLaTeX and am trying to view the output PDF. In my testing, I have not been using the terminal for compilation, only Texmaker.

EDIT:

When I add dimensions to the `pspicture` environment, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: give a _complete_  example! As you can see in my example it works with `xelatex`

Answer (score 1):

without the dimension parameters you'll get an area of 10cm x 10cm.
However, you can also draw any line without using the `pspicture` environment.
Then everything refers to the current point:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,pstricks}
\begin{document}

    \begin{flalign*}
        \text{(a) } -4 &&
    \end{flalign*}
    \begin{align*}
        &\left|z\right| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{(-4)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{16} = 4& \\
        &\tan \theta = \frac{0}{-4} = 0 & \\
        &\arctan (0) = 0, \pi& \\
        &z = 4(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)&
    \end{align*}
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<-}(2,1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either add dimensions to the `pspicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pstricks} 

\begin{document}
%
\begin{flalign*}
    \text{(a) } -4 &&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align*}
    &\left|z\right| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{(-4)^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{16} = 4& \\
    &\tan \theta = \frac{0}{-4} = 0 & \\
    &\arctan (0) = 0, \pi& \\
    &z = 4(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)&
\end{align*}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(2,1)%
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<-}(2,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or load `auto-pst-pdf`, use the `postscript` environment and compile with `pdflatex` (don't forget the `-shell-escape` switch under TeX Live or MacTeX, `--enable-write18` under MiKTeX)

```
\begin{postscript}%
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<-}(2,1)
\end{postscript}
```

[image]

Comment: I added an edit so you can see what I get when I attempt to add dimension to the `pspicture` environment.

Comment: I don't understand: the image corresponds to a pspicture with dimensions? Your code has none.

Comment: I ran the exact code you posted in your answer in Texmaker using the quickbuild (set to LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf + View PDF) option, yet I still get nothing. I end up with exactly what you have in your answer's image, just without the arrow. No errors are given in the console.